# How to deal with zero in dataset when trying to create a Dissimilarity matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, vegan

I have a simple question, which took me about hundred hours of googling today, and it is still unresolved. I hope someone here can miraculously answer to this.

I am trying to make a bray curtis dissimilarity matrix, and nMDS and then run a permanova for my species community data. The problem is that when I assign the community to each plot, not all the species are presents, for obvious reasons right? Now, the function metaMDS from the vegan package does not let me create anything. How do I deal with the zero in a matrix? Anybody have any scripts or ideas or any magical things to fix my day??

```
this is my code so far:
Crabdata3<- read.csv("Crab_Edited_Plots_02_12.csv")
str(Crabdata3)
Crabbie1= Crabdata3[,-(1:2),drop=FALSE]
Crabbie2 <-as.matrix(Crabbie1) 

is.matrix(Crabbie2)
Disscrabmatrix1 <-data.matrix(Crabbie2)





Disscrabmatrix2=matrix(Crabbie2,nrow=42,ncol=18, byrow =TRUE,
                       dimnames= list(paste("community", 1:42,sep="")
                                      ,paste(colnames(Crabbie2,1:18))))

example_NMDS=metaMDS(Disscrabmatrix2, distance ="bray", k=2)## number od reduced dimensions
```

This is the error I am getting

> example_NMDS=metaMDS(Disscrabmatrix2, distance ="bray", k=2)## number od reduced dimensions
>   Square root transformation
>   Wisconsin double standardization

```
Error in cmdscale(dist, k = k) : NA values not allowed in 'd'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In distfun(comm, method = distance, ...) :
  you have empty rows: their dissimilarities may be meaningless in method “bray”
2: In distfun(comm, method = distance, ...) : missing values in results
```

Comment: Could you please provide a sample dataset? It will help others who might want to test your code. Thanks.

Comment: So I have different species on my columns and different plots in the row, which I am now assuming are different communities.

Comment: The first warning tells us you have rows (samples) that are *all* zero. If you found nothing in those samples then we have nothing to map so you can't include those rows. filter those and proceed (I suspect that will fix the second warning and thence the Error).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-remove-rows-that-contains-all-zeros-in-an-r-data-frame

The author suggests using `df1[rowSums(df1[])>0,]` to remove all 0 rows. I'm trying to do a similar nMDS/PERMANOVA analysis and found this did the trick.

Cheers.